# Mysql query for search for multiple ids at a time

Tags: mysql

My senario as below,

1) my array is like below from where I want to search in database field = "state_id",

```
$stateIds= array(
[0]=>1,
[1]=>13,
[2]=>18,
[3]=>21,
[4]=>14,
);
```

in my db "state_id" field is store as ==> `1,2,3`

I have to show users whose state_id are present in array of $stateIds,

from above example that user's state_id is like `1,2,3` and if we check in array of $stateIds then id "1" is present there , so from query that user should come.

I have fired below query,

```
"FIND_IN_SET('".implode(',',$stateIds)."', state_id) OR ";
```

but it not worked,
Please anyone help me to solve it out?

Comment: I have almost no idea what you're talking about

Comment: I have update my question ,please check now

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Mysql's [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) takes first argument as single value to find in comma separated string like to find `b` in `a,b,c,d`

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
```

Using `FIND_IN_SET` you cannot match comma separated string with other comma separated string like `a,b` in `a,b,c,d`, However for your case you need to loop your array and put each single values in `FIND_IN_SET` something like

```
foreach($stateIds as $stateId){
    $query.= "FIND_IN_SET('".$stateId."', state_id) OR ";
}
```

Also if `state_id` is relational field i advise you to [normalize your structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), Its not a good idea to store relations in a single column

Comment: thanks for you quick answer, It will work fine ,but here we use loop ,is there any other way from where we can fire query without loop

Comment: I cannot think another way of doing the same but without loop, One way is if you know all stateids then put multiple clauses with different stateids values